# Loop para rodar scripts python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tenho um processo de loop para rodar scripts em paralelo, porém a VPS que vou ultilizar não permite usar paralelismo,
Nesse caso preciso criar um código como:

```
scripts = [
    'siteodonto.py',
    'siteponto.py',
    'sitemeta.py',
    ...
]


for i in scripts:
    python i
```

scripts tem uma lista do nome de todos script que preciso executar.
O que não estou sabendo fazer e como executar os scripts dentro desse outro.
`python i` [aqui seria chamando o script indice 1 `python siteodonto.py`] quando vai finalizando pega o outro até fechar a lista.

Comment: Qual o seu sistema operacional?

Comment: O sistema é Linux

Comment: O que é um "VPS que não permite usar paralelismo"?? VPS é "Vrtual Private Server - é uma máquina virtual - as você sempre tem acesso root dentro dela, pode rodar quantos processos quiser em paralelo. (pode ter apenas 1 core, mas pode disparar vários processos em paralelo e deixar o sistema operacional se virar)

Comment: Ele tem apenas um core, eu fiz isso mais o processador a Ram chegou em 100% e matou todos processos da VPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente rodá-los no terminal dentro de um arquivo `bash`. Para isso, crie um arquivo de extensão `sh` e inclua os comandos para rodar os arquivos de extensão `py` um após o outro. Finalmente, vá ao terminal e rode: `bash meuarq.sh`

Exemplo:

Arquivo python 1:

```
#primeiro programa extensão py
print('Hello world!')
```

Arquivo python 2:

```
#segundo programa extensão py
print('Hello world again!')
```

Arquivo bash:

```
#!usr/bin/bash
python python_program1.py
python python_program2.py
```

No terminal:

```
bash meuarq.sh
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
Hello world again!
```

Seguem formas alternativas de rodar os dois arquivos:

**Concomitante:**

```
 #!usr/bin/bash
python python_program1.py &
python python_program2.py &
```

**Condicional 1** (roda o segundo apenas se o primeiro rodar com sucesso):

```
#usr/bin/bash
python python_program1.py && python python_program2.py
```

**Condicional 2** (só roda o seguinte se o anterior falhar):

```
#usr/bin/bash
python python_program1.py || python python_program2.py
```

**Importante:** ambos os condicionais aceitam encadeamento

Alternativamente, você pode utilizar as funções, variáveis e objetos criados nos arquivos `programa1.py` e `programa2.py` em outro programa. Para isso, basta colocar esses arquivos na pasta em que você está trabalhando e importá-los como módulos:

```
from programa1 import *
from programa2 import *
```

Comment: Eu preciso deixar agendado no crojobs em apenas um arquivo, por isso pensei se há alguma forma de fazer com o python mesmo.

Comment: Pq vc não importa os arquivos como módulos  no último arquivo de extensão py e roda só esse último? Vou editar minha resposta para incluir essa opção

Comment: eles são scripts separados, uso para webscraping cada um é para fazer o webscraping em um site, não encontrei uma forma de fazer fora essa de ter um arquivo que chamasse os demais

Comment: mas vc vai ter sempre um arquivo que chama os demais, mesmo se a forma que vc imaginou inicialmente (com lista) funcionasse

Comment: Só uma pergunta, quando executo dessa forma,
python python_program1.py
python python_program2.py
sabe se executa um por vez ou todos de uma vez?

Comment: Tem como fazer das duas formas. Do jeito que está, ele vai fazer uma de cada vez. Vou editar minha resposta para incluir o código para rodar concomitantemente

Comment: Ele executou tudo de uma vez aqui por isso te perguntei.
Ele não pode executar tudo de uma vez porque o vps não suporta.

Comment: Veja se a edição que fiz te ajuda

Answer (score -3):

você pode querer usar o Python de forma assíncrona parar fazer uso do paralelismo, você pode chamar a função `asyncio.gather()`; uma forma simples de pôr isso em prática, por exemplo. Digamos que `main()` chame a sua função principal.

```
async def main(param)
# seu code ou programa principal
foo = Foo()
async def all_main():
    while True:
        L = await asyncio.gather(
            main(1),
            main(2),
        )
    continue
```