# Comando semelhante ao Try do python para shellscript?

Tags: python, shell-script, shell

Preciso formular um .sh para rodar um código caso o primeiro dê erro:

```
!#/bin/bash

python main.py
python3 main.py
```

Como se fosse uma exceção (Try/Except) do python.

Pensei em criar dois scripts .sh, para usar o Try num arquivo python, onde ele fosse decidir qual script roda sem erros, mas não sei se é viável. Caso seja, uma boa ideia, como mandar o python executar esses arquivos .sh?

Comment: pergunta análoga a esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427389/loop-para-rodar-scripts-python/427390#427390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar dois PIPEs `||` (OR)

```
!#/bin/bash

python main.py || python3 main.py
```

Se a sintaxe falhar no Python 2 (creio ser o seu objetivo) então ele irá executar o `python3`

[image: resultado no Debian]

No exemplo o script ficou:

```
import sys

version = sys.version

# Python 3
# value = f"Version: {version}"

# Python 2 e 3
value = "Version: " + version

print(version)
```

Veja que ele imprimiu `Version 2.7.16`

Agora se trocar os comentários das linhas para:

```
import sys

version = sys.version

# Python 3
value = f"Version: {version}"

# Python 2 e 3
# value = "Version: " + version

print(version)
```

O resultado será `Version 3.7.3` (no meu caso, sua máquina pode ter versões diferentes do Python 2 e 3)

[image: resultado python3 no debian]

Você deve ter notado que ainda apresenta qual foi o erro quando tentou executar no Python2 uma sintaxe do Python3, antes de tentar o Python3, se deseja "suprimir" esse tipo de mensagem no terminal pode usar o `2>/dev/null` no Python 2:

```
!#/bin/bash

python main.py 2>/dev/null || python3 main.py
```

No Python3 não precisa, afinal se falhar em ambos o erro é outra coisa.