# Como identificar o status de saída em um programa em bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Eu tenho um bash que roda uma série de scripts em outras linguagens. Quando passo de um script para outro eu uso a primeira forma de condicional (`&&`) que entendo como "rode o script seguinte se o atual rodou com sucesso" (sobre esses "conditional runnings" veja essa [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427389/loop-para-rodar-scripts-python/427390#427390)). Um exemplo seria:

```
#usr/bin/bash
python program1.py && python program2.py
```

Onde `program2.py` roda apenas se `program1.py` rodar com sucesso.

Ocorre que gostaria de printar uma mensagem no terminal caso ocorresse algum problema no script final, ou ao longo do programa (e outra mensagem em caso de sucesso).

O que pensei foi fazer um condicional do tipo:

```
 #!usr/bin/bash
#variável que gostaria que fosse dada pelo sistema dizendo se o código acima rodou com sucesso
status=$1

if (($status==0))
then
    echo "We finish this step sucessfully"
else
    echo "Some error occurred. Please, check warning and error messages above"
fi
```

Eu ouvi falar uma vez que em C existe uma variável de status de saída. Eu não sei bem, mas é algo como se a variável de status é igual 0, o programa rodou com sucesso, caso contrário, houve algum erro. Eu queria saber se existe algo equivalente em bash.

Comment: Desculpa se eu poorly phrased o título da pergunta, aceito sugestões para mudar para que ela seja mais fácil de encontrar para usuários que enfrentem o mesmo problema. É que o conceito de status de saída não está maduro na minha cabeça. A real é que nem sei if this is a thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo programa chamado por uma shell retorna um `exit code` mesmo que não esteja explicito no código do programa, ele retorna zero ao terminar sua execução ou qualquer outra coisa diferente de zero em caso de falha durante sua execução.

Explicite no seu programa python um código de saída de sucesso no fim do programa exemplo:

```
import sys
from exitstatus import ExitStatus

sys.exit(ExitStatus.success)
```

Depois no seu script facilite as coisas usando uma condições

```
python script.py
retVal=$?
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar o `$?`

Irá emitir 0:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Teste
echo Resultado: $?
```

Provavelmente irá emitir 127 pois o comando `foobar` falhou por não existir (ou pode ter outro comportamento dependendo do sistema):

```
#!/bin/bash

foobar
echo Resultado: $?
```

Esses valores podem ir de 0 a 255, zero sendo que executou com "sucesso", outros valores podem ser qualquer coisa, ou mais comum erros.

Em bash você também pode devolver o status retornado pelo ultimo programa a "saída" do bash, usando o o `exit`

```
#!/bin/bash

comando-especifico

exit $?
```

E pode também criar condições para o resultado:

```
#!/bin/bash

comando-especifico

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "O programa rodou bem"
else
  echo "O programa falhou"
fi
```

Comment: Pq `-eq 10`? Não poderia fazer `(($?==0))`?

Comment: Olá @Lucas eu digitei errado (foi na pressa), agora esta ok, é -ne 0, IFs no bash funcionam assim: https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta:

```
Programa && echo "### ok" || echo "### not ok"
```

Explicação:

```
programa && echo "ok"
   se programa retorna 0: 0 && x = 0 (nada mais é executado)
   se programa retorna não 0: não-0 && x = x (executa x)

programa || echo "not ok"
   se programa retorna nao-0: nao-0 || x = não-0 (nada mais é executado)
   se programa retorna 0: 0 || x = x (executa x)
```